# Calculate a sum of an array in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am trying to code something where you store 5 integers in an array and then calculate the sum of the 5 stored values. Then the 5 values ​​are printed and also the sum.

I tried this:

```
const int sizeOFarray = 5;
int b[sizeOFarray] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
int sum = 0;

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop ()
{
  // sum of array b
  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOFarray; i++ )
    sum += b[ i ];
  Serial.print('Sum of total elements of an array:') ;
  Serial.print(sum) ;
}
```

but it gives me a weird output:

```
720031034735031034750031034765031034780031034795031034810031034825031034840031034855031034870031034885031034900031034915031034930031034945031034960031034975031034990031034100503103
```

and it never stops.

Comment: Are you aware that the function `loop` loops indefinitely? Also note that `'Sum ... array:'` is a [multicharacter literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) of type `int`, not a c-style string.

Comment: do you have a suggestion for doing it? I just can't figure it out

Comment: Use double quotes to indicate a string. :-)

Comment: Print a newline after you print the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
const int sizeOFarray = 5;
int b[sizeOFarray] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};


int sum = 0;   // you initialize sum once.

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop ()
{
  // on the first pass sum == 0, no problem.
  // on the second pass, sum still holds the sum of values in the array.
  // to which you'll add again, creating the 'runaway' effect.   

  // sum of array b
  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOFarray; i++ )
    sum += b[ i ];

  // After the first pass, sum hold the correct value, that is good.

  Serial.print('Sum of total elements of an array:') ;
  Serial.print(sum) ;
}
```

One easy way to fix the problem is to move the declaration and initialization of variable sum inside loop(), adding a line feed to your printout will help as well, as in:

```
void loop ()
{
  int sum = 0; 
  // sum of array b
  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeOFarray; i++ )
    sum += b[ i ];

  Serial.print('Sum of total elements of an array:') ;
  Serial.println(sum) ;  // print sum and a newline. 
}
```

This should procuce this output:

```
Sum of total elements of an array:150
Sum of total elements of an array:150
Sum of total elements of an array:150
Sum of total elements of an array:150
Sum of total elements of an array:150
Sum of total elements of an array:150
```

Note: You could save some RAM space by doing away with variable SizeOfArray...

```
int b[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

void setup ()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}    

void loop()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]); ++i)
        sum += b[i];

    Serial.print("sum: "); 
    Serial.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can move all your code to void setup(), to get one conclusion

```
int b[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

void setup (){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.available();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]); ++i)
        sum += b[i];
    
    Serial.print("sum: "); 
    Serial.println(sum);        
}    

void loop()
{
    //delay(1000); no need
}
```

[Serial answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0gI4.png)